# WordPress - How to minimize my WordPress Query?

Tags: wordpress

I have a Wordpress query that I am running.  It queries through days of the week, and at the moment, the only way I know to repeat the query for each day, is to run the query 7 times, manually changing the day of the week.

Is there a way to only run the query once?

My code:

```
<?php
$args=array(
  'taxonomy' => 'day',
  'term' => 'monday',
  'post_type' => 'schedule',
  'meta_key' => 'tr_show_time', 
  'orderby' => 'tr_show_time', 
  'order' => 'asc',  
  'posts_per_page' => 24,
  'caller_get_posts'=> 1
);
$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

My code to execute for the schedule.

<?php endwhile; } wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

So at the moment, I have to change the "term" in each query, and have the same query 7 times.  There must be a better way.

If there is a better way, can someone answer and teach me the answer?

Thanks

EDIT:  I just want add that each "day" on the schedule has 24 items, one for each hour of the day, and they are displayed in order from 00:00 until 24:00 (00:00, 01:00, 02:00, etc) so this "ordering" needs to be maintained.  The only way I could see to do this was to query each day seperatly, hence why I had 7 queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it myself:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$d=date("D");
$current_day = date ('l');
?>
    <ul>
      <?php
$args=array(
  'taxonomy' => 'day',
  'term' => $current_day,
  'post_type' => 'schedule',
  'meta_key' => 'tr_show_time', 
  'orderby' => 'tr_show_time', 
  'order' => 'asc',  
  'posts_per_page' => 24,
  'caller_get_posts'=> 1
);
$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
      <?php $show_name = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'tr_show_name', true ); ?>
      <?php $show_time = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'tr_show_time', true ); ?>

my code here.

      <?php endwhile; } wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `tax_query` parameter

```
$args = array(
  'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'day',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday' )
        )
    ),
  'post_type' => 'schedule',
  'meta_key' => 'tr_show_time', 
  'orderby' => 'tr_show_time', 
  'order' => 'asc',  
  'posts_per_page' => 24,
  'caller_get_posts'=> 1
);
```

For more information read up on [taxonomy queries](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)

Comment: Wouldn't this intermingle all the items together?  Each day of the week has 24 items in it, one for each hour of the day.  Using a term array, wouldn't it put all of the "00:00" items together, then all of the "01:00" items together, etc?

Comment: Hmm you never mentioned that from the start... But I would say to first try it and see what it spits out.